# Drupal 7 - how to add another button to a webform?

Tags: php, drupal, button, addition, drupal-webform

I was wondering, does anyone know how can I add another button to a webform in Drupal 7 in addition to the submit button?  I tried looking through Google as well as asking this question at the Drupal forums, with no luck.  Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Webform is a drupal form and you can use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/hook_form_alter): Lets say you have a custom module called **mymodule** and your webform id is '**webform_client_form_XXXXX**'. Then use the sample code below.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter.
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'webform_client_form_XXXXX':
      $form['actions']['custom_submit']  = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Custom Button'),
        '#submit' => array('mymodule_custom_submit'),
      );
      $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_custom_validate';
      break;
  }
}
/**
 * Custom validation handler for your webform.
 */
function mymodule_custom_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // your validation code
}
/**
 * Custom submit handler for your form
 */
function mymodule_custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // your submit handler code
}
```

---

UPDATE:

You would have to substitute instances of **mymodule** in the above code with yoru **modules's name**. Also i have modified the hook_form_alter a little. I suggest you move your submit button under `$form['actions']`, so it would appear next to the current submit button.

### To Clear Cache:

visit `/admin/config/development/performance` and click on **Clear all cache** button.

### To find the weform form-id:

[This](http://w3courses.com/content/find-formid-webforms-use-captcha-module-drupal) tutorial on net discuss about how to find the form id. Please note that the id used in the form tag will have '-' (hyphen), that has to be replaced with '_'(underscore) to get the form-id.

Another method is to print the $form_id variable in hook_form_alter ( the function which we have defined above ) and visit the webform page. If there are no other forms on that page the printed id would be the one that correspond to webform.  If you enable [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module then it is easier to display debugging information using excellent krumo library.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter.
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Below function would print out the form id in message area if devel module
  // is enabled on the site.
  dpm($form_id);
  switch ($form_id) {
```

remove `dpm( $form_id );` afterwards.

Comment: I created a module Webform Extra, and added this code.  However, the custom button still doesn't show up.  Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you replace all the instances of **mymodule** with **webform_extra**? Hint: there are five :) where webform_extra is your module name. Also make sure you clear your cache for hooks to be recognized. Also make sure you have used exact id of the webform in switch statement instead of **webform_client_form_XXXXX**

Comment: Yep, I replaced all instances of mymodule with webform_extra.  Now, how do I clear the cache hooks, and where to I find the ID of the webform?

Comment: I have added few more details in my answer regarding your concerns :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  This apparently works, however, I would prefer to put the custom button to the right of the submit button rather than the left.

Comment: You can use #weight property to change the position at which they are rendered. For more information regarding that please read http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#weightval

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the webform id is easier than the methods described above. You only need to go to: content->webforms and place the mouse cursor over the edit option belonging to the webform you want the id. 
Down the navigator screen the original path in the format node/id will appear. That node number is the XXX in webform_client_form_XXX.

Answer (score -1):

You can use type Markup in webform. Theme the markup as it look a like the button same as your submit button.

and write JS for that. For e.g, you want to give reset button then onclick event should empty the values in those fields. Try this.

Comment: Thanks.  However, I would prefer it to be to the right of the submit button instead of above it.  I don't think this is possible with markup.

Comment: Though it might not render on right side you can use CSS to move it right.

Answer (score -1):

first create markup  in webform for button then use java script for that when click on this it process request based on your requirement.

Comment: javascript is used to process request on client side. Buttons are used to submit the form and get the request processed in server side. So i am guessing you would have to use ajax and a custom menu handler to handle the submit... which is kinda lengthy process.